# Bootstrap 3 Datepicker

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, datepicker

Суть: Не работает русская локаль. [страница разработчиков](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)

Код

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker2'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
                    locale: 'ru'
                });
            });
        </script>
    </div>
```

А вот если исправить код на

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker();
    });
</script>
```

То календарь работает, но нет русского локализации. Подскажите где косяк?

Comment: Проверьте какая версия бутсрапа у вас, вдруг он устарел.
Смените браузер расскажите о результате...

Comment: Проблема не  в версии, если убрать параметр локализации то все работает. Браузер и т.д проверял.

Comment: правильно ли я понял, что нету только самих переводов? Попробуйте **language: 'ru'**

Comment: Да, нету только самих переводов, language: 'ru'  пробовал уже.

Comment: Локали, которые использует этот datepicker изначально исходят из библиотеки moment. У меня вопрос - каким образом была установлена данная библиотека? Вручную или с помощью bower? Нужно проверить, чтобы moment был правильно подключен.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проверьте, подключена ли у вас библиотека **moment-with-locales.js**

Comment: Не была подключена, спасибо все ок

Answer (score 0):

У меня была такая же проблема. Попробуй добавить такое:

```
$.datepicker.regional['ru'] = {
        closeText: 'Закрыть',
        prevText: '&#x3c;Пред',
        nextText: 'След&#x3e;',
        currentText: 'Сегодня',
        monthNames: ['Январь','Февраль','Март','Апрель','Май','Июнь',
            'Июль','Август','Сентябрь','Октябрь','Ноябрь','Декабрь'],
        monthNamesShort: ['Янв','Фев','Мар','Апр','Май','Июн',
            'Июл','Авг','Сен','Окт','Ноя','Дек'],
        dayNames: ['воскресенье','понедельник','вторник','среда','четверг','пятница','суббота'],
        dayNamesShort: ['вск','пнд','втр','срд','чтв','птн','сбт'],
        dayNamesMin: ['Вс','Пн','Вт','Ср','Чт','Пт','Сб'],
        dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
        firstDay: 1,
        isRTL: false
    };
    $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['ru']);
```

А потом просто инициализировать:

```
$("#datetimepicker2").datepicker();
```

Answer (score 0):

Также если у Вас подключена библиотека **moment-with-locales.js** , но при этом все-равно не инициализируется русская локаль, то просто поменяйте порядок загрузки библиотек. Сначала **moment.js** после **moment-with-locales.js**