# Как установить русский язык в Datarangepicker?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, daterangepicker

Уже был подобный вопрос ([Datepicker](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/439087/bootstrap-3-datepicker)), сделал все, как там написано, подключил все библиотеки

```
<script src="js/moment/min/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/moment/min/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
```

Вот input для daterange:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Срок и время выполнения плана:</label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-addon">
      <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control pull-right" id="datarange">
  </div>
  <!-- /.input group -->
</div>
```

Вот js:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#datarange').daterangepicker({ locale: 'ru', timePicker: true, timePickerIncrement: 30, format: 'MM/DD/YYYY h:mm A' });
  });
</script>
```

Но все равно остается английский язык [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как это исправить? (В консоли нет никаких ошибок)

Comment: Вот у человека возникла [похожая проблема](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34079667/configuring-language-in-bootstrap-date-range-picker) с испанским языком. Там есть пару вариантов решения этой проблемы, выберите удобный для вас.

Comment: Спасибо, я видел этот вопрос, но думал есть решение как-то по другому сделать, в ответе напишу решение...

Comment: от Oleg'a не пробовали решение? где 30 лайков стоит, может просто другую библиотеку вам подключить `momentjs`?

Comment: Moment js, я так понял, хранит локали для библиотеки Datarange. И да, я пробовал ответ от Олега, но ничего не вышло, не знаю почему, а проблему надо было быстро решить, поэтому не стал разбираться из-за чего у меня не работает, а использовал вариант, который у меня работал)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так решил проблему:

```
<script>
    $('#datarange').daterangepicker({ "locale": {
        "format": "MM/DD/YYYY",
        "separator": " - ",
        "applyLabel": "Сохранить",
        "cancelLabel": "Назад",
        "daysOfWeek": [
            "Вс",
            "Пн",
            "Вт",
            "Ср",
            "Чт",
            "Пт",
            "Сб"
        ],
        "monthNames": [
            "Январь",
            "Февраль",
            "Март",
            "Апрель",
            "Май",
            "Июнь",
            "Июль",
            "Август",
            "Сентябрь",
            "Октябрь",
            "Ноябрь",
            "Декабрь"
        ],
        "firstDay": 1
    }, timePicker: true, timePickerIncrement: 30, format: 'MM/DD/YYYY h:mm A' });
</script>
```